# What is the correct way to handle incorrect charsets when reading strings from a URL resource?

Tags: java, character-encoding, resources

I am reading a file which is a classpath resource:

```
URL dictionary = Main.class.getResource("/british-english.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dictionary.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
List<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How should I handle the case where the file is encoded with a different character set, say UTF_16? Is there a way to detect this, except by looking at the list of strings, to see whether they are English words?

Answer (score 0):

https://tika.apache.org/0.8/api/org/apache/tika/parser/txt/CharsetDetector.html. 
 Please try with apache tika api for charset detection on the supplied input.